# AVL Tree Insertion Without Recursion C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am using the Following code to Implement the AVL Tree Insertion but its not display in proper order nor its updating height I also left some function because when insertion completed than i will be able to complete those fucntions

**AVLNode.cpp**

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "AVLNode.h"
    using namespace std;

    AVLNode::AVLNode(string ss, string na){
        ssn = ss;
        name = na;
        height = 0;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        parent = NULL;
    }
```

**AVLNode.h**

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    struct AVLNode{
      string ssn;
      string name;
      AVLNode *left;
      AVLNode *right;
      AVLNode *parent;
      int height;

      AVLNode(string ss, string na);
    };
```

**AVLTree.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "AVLTree.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

AVLTree::AVLTree(){
    root = NULL;
}

AVLTree::~AVLTree(){


}

AVLNode* AVLTree::getRoot(){
    return root;
}


// search value ss in the AVL tree
bool AVLTree::find(string ss){
    if (root == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    AVLNode* node = root;

    while (node != NULL) {
        if (ss.compare(node->ssn) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        if (ss.compare(node->ssn) < 0) {
            node = node->left;
        }
        else{
            node = node->right;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// return the height of the subtree rooted at node
// if subtree is empty, height is -1
// if subtree has one node, height is 0
int AVLTree::height(AVLNode* node){

    if(node != NULL){
        return node->height;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

// return the balance factor of the node
int AVLTree::balanceFactor(AVLNode* node){
    return height(node->left) - height(node->right);
}

// update the height of the node
// this should be done whenever the tree is modified
void AVLTree::updateHeight(AVLNode* node){
    int hl = height(node->left);
    int hr = height(node->right);
    node->height = (hl > hr ? hl : hr) + 1;
}


// rotate right the subtree rooted at node
// return the new root of the subtree
AVLNode* AVLTree::rotateRight(AVLNode* node){
    AVLNode* lp = node->left;      // left child of node
    if (node->parent != NULL) {  // node is not root
        if (node->parent->left == node) { // node is a left child
            node->parent->left = lp;
        }else{
            node->parent->right = lp;     // node is a right child
        }
    }

    if (lp->right != NULL) {           // pointer update
        lp->right->parent = node;
    }

    lp->parent = node->parent;
    node->left = lp->right;
    lp->right = node;
    node->parent = lp;
    updateHeight(node);                   // after rotation, update height
    updateHeight(lp);                     // after rotation, update height
    if (node == root) {
        root = lp;
    }
    return lp; // lp is the new root of the subtree
}


// rotate left the subtree rooted at node
// return the new root of the subtree
AVLNode* AVLTree::rotateLeft(AVLNode* node){
    AVLNode* rp = node->right;
    if (node->parent!=NULL) {
        if (node->parent->left == node) {
            node->parent->left = rp;
        }else{
            node->parent->right = rp;
        }
    }

    if (rp->left != NULL) {
       rp->left->parent = node;
    }

    rp->parent = node->parent;

    node->right = rp->left;
    rp->left = node;
    node->parent = rp;
    node->parent = rp;
    updateHeight(node);
    updateHeight(rp);
    if (node == root) {
        root = rp;
    }
    return rp;
}


// rebalance a tree rooted at node
// return the new root of the subtree
AVLNode* AVLTree::balance(AVLNode* node){
    updateHeight(node);
    if (balanceFactor(node) == 2) {
        if (balanceFactor(node->left) < 0) {
            node->left = rotateLeft(node->left); // for left right case
        }

        AVLNode* temp = rotateRight(node);
        updateHeight(temp);
        return temp;
    }

    if (balanceFactor(node) == -2) {
        if (balanceFactor(node->right) > 0) {
            node->right = rotateRight(node->right);  // for right left case
        }
        AVLNode* temp2 = rotateLeft(node);
        updateHeight(temp2);
        return temp2;
    }
    return node;
}

// insert a new node with (ss, na) to the AVL tree
// if there exists ss value, return false
// otherwise, insert it, balance the tree, return true
bool AVLTree::insert(string ss, string na){
     AVLNode *newNode=new AVLNode(ss,na);

     AVLNode *Iterator;
     if(root==NULL){
       cout<<"Root Node Inserted"<<endl;
       root=newNode;

     } else {

         Iterator = root; 
         int rootTempValue = atoi((Iterator->ssn).c_str()); 
         int addTempValue = atoi((newNode->ssn).c_str());



         if(rootTempValue <= addTempValue  ){
              // Right Portion of the tree
              while(Iterator->right != NULL){

                         cout << "In the Right portion" <<endl;


                       int rootTempValue2 = atoi((Iterator->right->ssn).c_str()); 
                       int addTempValue2 = atoi((newNode->ssn).c_str()) ;

                       if(rootTempValue2 <= addTempValue2 )             
                            Iterator = Iterator->right;
                       else 
                            Iterator = Iterator->left;       


                   //Iterator = Iterator->right;


              }

              Iterator->right = newNode ;
              newNode->parent = Iterator ;


         } else {


              // Left Portion of the tree
              while(Iterator->left != NULL){
                   //Iterator = Iterator->left;



                    int rootTempValue2 = atoi((Iterator->left->ssn).c_str()); 
                    int addTempValue2 = atoi((newNode->ssn).c_str()) ;

                    if(rootTempValue2 <= addTempValue2 )             
                          Iterator = Iterator->right;
                    else 
                         Iterator = Iterator->left;       



              }
              newNode->parent = Iterator;
              newNode->right = NULL ;
              newNode->left = NULL;
              Iterator->left = newNode ;

              cout << "In the left portion : " <<Iterator->left->ssn<<endl;

         }

     }

     balance(newNode);
     updateHeight(newNode);


    return true;
}


AVLNode* AVLTree::maxOfSubtree(AVLNode* node){
    if (node == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    while (node->right != NULL) {
        node = node->right;
    }
    return node;
}

// delete the node containing value ss
// if there is not such node, return false
// otherwise, delete the node, balance the tree, return true
bool AVLTree::deleteNode(string ss){

    // please implement here
    return true;

}

// internal function
// do not call it directly
void AVLTree::print(AVLNode* x, int indent){
    if(x == NULL) 
         return;
    if (x->right != NULL) {
        print(x->right, indent+4);
    }

    if (indent != 0) {
        cout << std::setw(indent) << ' ';
    }

    if(x->right != NULL){
        cout << " /\n" << std::setw(indent) << ' ';
    }

    cout << x->ssn << endl;

    if (x->left != NULL) {
        cout << std::setw(indent) << ' ' <<" \\\n";
        print(x->left, indent+4);
    }

}

// print out the structure of the binary tree
// use it for debugging, I love this function
void AVLTree::print(){
    int count = 0;
    print(root, count);
}


// it does not level order traversal
// it prints out the number of node
// use it mainly for debugging
void AVLTree::levelOrder(){

// please implement it
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "AVLTree.h"


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  AVLTree temp;
  temp.insert("05", "a");
  temp.insert("04", "b");
  temp.insert("09", "c");
  //temp.insert("03", "d");
  //temp.insert("06", "d");
 // temp.insert("07", "d");
  //temp.insert("02", "d");

  temp.print();
  cout<<endl;
  cout<<"The Height Of The Tree is :" << temp.height(temp.getRoot())<<endl;

   cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some remarks: `AVLTree.h` is not present in your question. The destructor of `AVLTree` should delete the nodes owned by the tree. To debug such a class, you can add a `bool invariant() const` method that test if your internal structure is consistent. You can then call it before and after any insertion to detect which insertion breaks your invariant. Then you can more efficiently debug with a debugger.

Comment: can you write that function which i can check how to test it

Comment: I have written it in the answer. It is not tested, so you are likely to correct the compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AVLTree` has a complex class invariant and expressing it is generally a good idea for an efficient debug.

If you write a method like

```
bool
AVLTree::invariant() const {
  if (root == NULL)
    return true;

  std::stack<AVLNode*> stack;
  stack.push_back(root);
  while (!stack.empty()) {
    AVLNode* currentNode = stack.back();
    int leftHeight = -1, rightHeight = -1;
    if (currentNode->left) {
      leftHeight = currentNode->left->height;
      if (currentNode->left->parent != currentNode)
        return false;
      if (currentNode->left.height+1 != currentNode->height)
        return false;
    }
    if (currentNode->right) {
      rightHeight = currentNode->right->height;
      if (currentNode->left->parent != currentNode)
        return false;
      if (currentNode->left.height+1 != currentNode->height)
        return false;
    }
    if (leftHeigth > rightHeigth+1 || rightHeight > leftHeight+1)
      return false;
    if (currentNode->left)
      stack.push_back(currentNode->left);
    else {
      do {
        stack.pop_back();
        AVLNode* parentNode = !stack.empty() ? stack.back() : NULL;
        if (currentNode && parentNode->right != currentNode && parentNode->right) {
          stack.push_back(parentNode->right);
          break;
        };
        currentNode = parentNode;
      } while (currentNode);
    };
  };
  return true;
}
```

you can then debug your `main` function by adding into it the following code

```
assert(temp.invariant());
temp.insert("05", "a");
assert(temp.invariant());
temp.insert("04", "b");
assert(temp.invariant());
temp.insert("09", "c");
assert(temp.invariant());
```

As soon as you have identified the insertion that fails, you just have to break on the `return false;` in the `invariant` method that is executed. At this point you should be able to understand the origin of the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `std::stack`? Recursion is basically just looping off of the call stack as it is.

```
if (!root)
   root = new AVLNode(ss, na);
else
{
   AVLNode *current = root;
   AVLNode *previous = NULL;
   std::stack<AVLNode*> rstack;

   while (current != NULL)
   {
      previous = current;
         //Use String Compare instead of cast
      if (ss.compare(current->ssn) < 0) //If ss less than current
          ...

      rstack.push(previous);
   }
   ...
   ...

   while (!rstack.empty())
   {
      rstack.top() = balance(rstack.top());
      rstack.pop();
   }
}
```